# How can I make my footer stay at the bottom with a dynamically re-sizable form?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form that adds rows in with the jQuery .afer() method (on the push of a button).  My footer is always positioned at the bottom of the page when it loads, but if I click the button enough times, the footer stays where it was, and it overlaps the rows.  How can I make it recognize that the table is getting larger, and it needs to move down?  I am willing and comfortable using solutions involving CSS or JavaScript.

CSS

```
.footer
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(".gameSchedule .addEvent").bind('click', function () {
    $(".gameSchedule tr:nth-child(2)").after('<tr><td><input type="text"</td><td><input type="text"</td><td><input type="text"</td><td><input type="text"<td><td><input type="text"</td></tr>');
});
```

HTML

```
<form name="gameForm" class="gameSchedule"><!--FORM FOR GAMES-->
<table  >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Team Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Opponent/Event</td>
        <td>H/A</td>
        <td>Location</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"</td>
        <td><input type="text"</td>
        <td><input type="text"</td>
        <td><input type="text"</td>
        <td><input type="text"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" class="addEvent" value="Add Event"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net with more of the html and css. It would be helpful to see where the footer is positioned in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem. This works like a charm!

CSS

```
#Content{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var docHeight = $('#content').height();
    var wantedHeight = docHeight - 376;/*Minus header and footer combined*/ 
    $('#content').css({ "min-height": wantedHeight });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put your footer in a div with an id of 'footer', Then use this jquery.

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {

    var footerHeight = 0,
       footerTop = 0,
       $footer = $("#footer");

    var contentHeight = 0,
       contentTop = 0,
       $content = $("#content");



    positionFooter();

    function positionFooter() {

        footerHeight = $footer.height();
        footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - footerHeight) + "px";

        contentHeight = $content.height();
        contentTop = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - contentHeight) + "px";


        if (($(document.body).height() + footerHeight + contentHeight) < $(window).height()) {
            $footer.css({
                position: "absolute"
            }).animate({
                top: footerTop
            }, 0)
        } else {
            $footer.css({
                position: "static"
            })
        }
    }
    $(window)
           .scroll(positionFooter)
           .resize(positionFooter)
});
```

Comment: Does the jquery need to be in a $(document).ready function?  That example didn't quite work when I tried it.

Comment: Just needs to be in a script tag.. Your jquery script include needs to be there too.

Comment: Ok, tweaked the jquery a bit. Also, wrap your table in a div named content. Confirmed it works.

Comment: I still can't get it to work.  I think the rest of my code may be a little too complicated.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Update:  I have it working when I set the min-height of the content ID to 100% and use no Jquery.  The only problem is that now the footer is about 300 pixels farther down than it should be.  Is there anyway I can set the min-height to be (100% - 300px)